# Change X settings to boot into laptop with non working screen using an external monitor

Tags: video, nvidia, xorg

My laptop committed suicide. Is there a way I can boot into my ubuntu using an external screen?

Ubuntu 10.10
video: Nvidia 9500 gm i think

I can get dual screen upto and until the ubuntu login screen at which point it goes back into laptop display only. Then I can just type and enter my password. The system (i assume boots into ubuntu) but I got no way of going onto the x or nvidia settings to change my display to external monitor

**EDIT**

well I booted into terminal using control shift F1 i think, and now I'm trying to reporgram x.org, but strangely it seems bland with not a lot of settings in it

**EDIT 2**
xrandr returns "Can't open display"

**EDit 3**

after some messing around with xrandr and xinit ... my x.org only displays one monitor instead of two in its settings although both, i.e. the laptop and external screens are both connected.

**EDIT 4**
it seems that x.org now has a "screen" and "monitor" section, I can't seem to be able to boot linux into monitor. I get a "Monitor is not a valid keyword" in this subsection

Answer (score 1):

Just plug in a monitor, and the monitor will mirror what the laptop screen ought to be showing. You can use System -> Preferences -> Monitors to get the resolution right, and turn off the laptop screen (so Ubuntu doesn't try to render everything twice).

Comment: The screen mirrors just for the login, once it goes to ubuntu it goes away. I tried doing fn + split screen, but that didnt' work

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> should get you into a terminal. In there, install `openssh-server` so you can log into the machine from the network, which will be more comfortable:

```
sudo aptitude install openssh-server (from memory)
```

Then, log in locally (you will lose your screen initially).

Also, log in remotely via ssh.

Set your remote ssh session environment so you can affect the X server:

```
export DISPLAY=:
```

Now you can play around with variations on xrandr --auto etc on the remote ssh session, and you will be driving your desktop login. For example:

```
xrandr -q
```

... which should tell you the current status.

```
xrandr --auto
```

... which might Just Work. Or maybe (as a guess from memory)

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --off --output VGA1 --auto
```

Good luck ;-)